# Why are my <a> elements changing back to their default color after clicking on them

Tags: jquery

I'm new into Jquery and I was trying to make `onClick` function that is supposed to change color of element to, for example, yellow.

It is perfectly working for `h1` elements but `a` elements just blink with yellow color on click and they change back to their default color. I tried to search it myself but I found nothing.

```js
var containerUp = $('.upperside-shit');
var buttons = containerUp.find("a");
var nadpis = containerUp.find("h1")
console.log(buttons.length);

buttons.click(function() {
  $(this).css("color", "yellow");
});

nadpis.click(function() {
  $(this).css("color", "yellow");
})
```

```css
.upperside-shit ul,
.upperside-shit h1,
.icons,
.upperside-shit ul li a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.upperside-shit ul,
.icons,
.upperside-shit h1 {
  width: 31.75%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.icons {
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}

.icons i {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.icons i:last-child {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.upperside-shit ul,
.upperside-shit ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.upperside-shit a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.categories li a {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.upperside-shit ul li a:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="upperside-shit clearfix">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="">Woman</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Men</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Children</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <div class="icons">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i>
  </div>

  <ul class="categories clearfix">
    <li><a href="">Button </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Button </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Button </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Button </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Button </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Button </a></li>
    <li><a href="">Button </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your links `<a>` are navigating to their href - which happens to be `href=""` so **reloads the page**.   Remove the `href=""` *or* add `return false;` to your click event handler or use [`preventDefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: If you don't intend the `<a>` to link anywhere (ie navigate away) and they are actually "buttons" (as in your code) then use `<button type='button`>` instead; for accessibility reasons.  You can use css to style a button so it looks like a link.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yep so basically i need to use some localStorage or some back-end method to save that css so it won't change back to default. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @milderengen No, @freedomn-m is saying you should use a `<button>` tag instead of an `<a>` tag (and style it in your CSS as you would any other element), which will prevent the clicking of the `<a>` tag from causing the page to reload.

Comment: Depends on whether you're expecting them to stay that colour when you do *intentionally* reload the page.

Comment: Yeah this will solve the problem which i explained in question, i am not saying it is not. But i am trying to create some wannabe E-shop and i only need yellow color on those buttons that indicate on which page i am browsing. Anyway, i did that with simple if statement that checks class of main element and adds color & font-weight  accordingly to right "button".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) function , which will disable the native behavior of element

```js
buttons.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).css("color", "yellow");
});
```